# uploading an image ml model to flask app but getting error

Tags: python

this is a flask application , i load the model and then read the file and then try to predict  but  facing this error  ,

below is the code:

```
   import os
import numpy as np
from  flask import Flask
from flask import request
import cv2
import imutils
from flask import render_template
import pickle
app = Flask(__name__)

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator ,load_img,img_to_array
classifier = tf.keras.models.load_model("ourModel.h5")



UPLOAD_FOLDER = "./static"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'jpg','jpeg'}


def allowed_files(file):
    return '.' in file and file.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


def predict(file):
    
    images = cv2.imread(file)
    
    images = imutils.resize(images,width=320)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(images,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5))
    blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray,cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT,kernel)
    _,thresh = cv2.threshold(blackhat,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh,None)
    (cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    avgcntarea = np.mean([cv2.contourArea(k) for k in cnts])

    digits = []
    boxes = []
    for (i,c) in enumerate(cnts):
        
        
        
        
    
        if cv2.contourArea(c)<avgcntarea/10:
            
            
            
            
            continue
        
    
            mask = np.zeros(gray.shape,dtype="uint8")
            
                    
            (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                    
            hull = cv2.convexHull(c)
                    
            cv2.drawContours(mask,[hull],-1,255,-1)
                    
                    
            mask = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh,thresh,mask=mask)
                    
            digit = mask[y-8:y+h+8,x-8:x+w+8]
                    
            digit = cv2.resize(digit,(28,28))
                    
            boxes.append((x,y,w,h))
                    
            digits.append(digit)
            lists = []
             
          
  
            digits = np.array(digits)
            digits = digits.reshape(digits.shape[0],28,28,1)
           
            
            labels = classifier.predict_classes(digits) 
       

    for (x,y,w,h),label in sorted(zip(boxes,labels)):
        
        
        
        
        cv2.rectangle(images,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),1)
        cv2.putText(images,str(label),(x+2,y-5),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1.0,(0,255,0),2)

        lists.append(label)

    
    return lists


        

@app.route("/",methods=["GET","POST"])
def upload_predict():
    if request.method == "POST":
        image_file = request.files["image"]


        
        # if file is empty
        filename = image_file.filename
        if filename == '':
             newerr = " File is empty"
             return render_template("index.html",error=newerr)


        # if file is not supported or not allow ! we will perform the below validation

        if allowed_files(filename) == False:
            newerr = " upload error : this file  format is not allowed"
            return render_template("index.html",error=newerr)




        if image_file:
            image_location = os.path.join(
                UPLOAD_FOLDER,
                image_file.filename
            )
            image_file.save(image_location)
            
            output = predict(image_location)
            print(image_location)


            return render_template("index.html",prediction=output)
    

    return render_template("index.html",prediction=0)




@app.route("/Accuracy")
def Accuracy():
    return render_template('Accuracy.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=12000,debug=True)
```

this is the error:

error m UnboundLocalError: local variable 'labels' referenced before assignment

i ahve been running the same code on jupyter it works fine but here i am getting error

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have a `continue` in here

```
 if cv2.contourArea(c)<avgcntarea/10:         
            continue 
            mask = np.zeros(gray.shape,dtype="uint8")
```

which will skip the for loop `for (i,c) in enumerate(cnts):` and will not create the variable label.